# Activating Tabs with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to use the tab feature of the Bootstrap CSS. I've been following the code here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage
On the section Methods. However, when I click the tabs that I have, it doesn't appear to switch after changing the text to see whether it switches or not. What script do I use to switch tabs?

Comment: Could you provide HTML you used?

Comment: It's the exact HTML code displayed on the section "Methods" in the link I posted. Also, inside a <div class="Container">.

Comment: I pasted code ffrom bootstrap to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3Nbh/ , in my opinion it works fine

Comment: What? Oh wow. Hmm... I turns out I needed to use the jQuery plugin then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should attach the jQuery and the bootstrap.min.js to your page. Then it will work for sure!!

Good luck!